# Unable to execute CodedUI tests from VSTS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests, functional-testing

I have created a CodedUI project in VS2017, i am able to execute the tests on my machine directly in VS2017.

I can easily bind test methods to VSTS online Test case. However, when i build and deploy the project and the assemblies on VSTS online and try to lauchn them from VSTS, i always got errors related to Deploying a Test agent on target machine(s) to be able to execute the test.

Just for information, the web pages we want to test are on a on-premise website, so not accessible from internet.

Do someone know how to make this work, ie how to set up the test machine, how to set up the Test agent on that machine (the microsoft documentation is not reallly clear about that), and what we need to make VSTS be able to communicate with our on-premise test machine.

Comment: In order to run a Coded UI test, you will a dedicated machine that you can deploy the test agent and test to. So I have two questions for you. First, are you using the hosted build agent in VSTS? Second, do you have a machine on premise you can dedicate as the test agent?

Comment: Yes, we are using hosted build agent and are currently working on creating a test server on-premise. Can we use the Hosted agent with on premise test machine?

Comment: You can if you publicly expose the test machine. This opens you up to a lot of security issues. Your best option is to setup an on premise build and test machine.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is that you can setup a private build agent that can access test machine, then build the project through this private agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).

If you want to use Hosted agent, your test machine need to be accessible from internet.